# Fullscreen resolution issue using videoJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, video.js

We are displaying the video using videoJS library in bootstrap modal, the video looks fine in modal popup. However, when we try to see the video in full screen mode the video look quite blur.

So, my is question do we need to set the resolution if going for full screen mode OR it is explicitly handled by VideoJS?

How can the video will be seen in correct resolution in full screen mode using videoJS library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope its a Progressive download via a HTTP server, check your network download speed/video quality, because if once video download starts the video-quality will be locked. its a common issue for progressive downloads.

Comment: Thats fine.. but I am testing the application locally and accessing the videos from folder which is inside of the solution ?